# Simple procedure generated map

Tags: logic, dynamically-generated, infinity

I'm developing a game, and i just faced a logic problem, a little bit annoying...

Here's the deal: imagine a scenary:
[image]
Where the black square around the player is the camera view, and the red dots, are the randomly generated objects

- the game is something like angry birds, its a physics game, which you trhow the object, so, the player is always going foward to the right, how can i make 
  to the game always generates the red dots and disable the older ones that they are no longer visible? keep in mind that the camera always follows the player, and i don't want that the player notices the instantiation

Here's a gif to understand a little bit more:

[http://i.imgur.com/0Ku8g2P.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/0Ku8g2P.gifv)

i just need some other opinions to make this happen, its just a logic problem haha
Thank you very much!
sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What is the actual problem here?  Just generate new dots in advance, and delete any dot that's left of the screen.

Comment: so, i disable the dots that is left to the player position - screen.width / 2, so this way the player can't see the dots being disabled, and start generating new dots when?